# SQLAlchemy - Query has only expression-based entities

Tags: python, asynchronous, sqlalchemy

I'm getting this SQLAlchemy error when try to select specific columns from a table while also retrieving the relationships. I'm using an async session as well.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Query has only expression-based entities; attribute loader options for Mapper[ModelA(modela)] can't be applied here.
```

Here's the query in question:

```py
async def get(self, fields):
        # parse_fields gets the column and relationship of a SQLAlchemy table model, i.e ModelA.id or ModelA.my_relationship
        columns, relationships = self.parse_fields(fields, ModelA)
        stmnt = select(*columns)
        if len(relationships):
            stmnt = stmnt.options(selectinload(*relationships))
        result = await self.session.execute(stmnt)
        return result.all()
```

Models in Question

```
class ModelA(Base):
    __tablename__ = "modela"
    name = Column(Text, nullable=True)
    bs = relationship("ModelB", back_populates="a", lazy="joined")


class ModelB(Base):
    __tablename__ = "modelb"
    name = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    a_id = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey("a.id"), nullable=False)
    a = relationship("ModelA", back_populates="bs", lazy="joined")
```

I'm trying to retrieve the columns and relationships from the table while still controlling which columns or relationships are be retrieved. The issue is, when I select specific columns while also selecting specific relationships of a table it's giving the mentioned errors. But when I execute something like a query like `select(ModelA).options(selectinload(ModelA.my_relationship)` it works but it gives me all columns and relationships. When I run something like `select(*columns)` where columns are the SQLAlchemy table model columns, I get the columns but not the relationships I want. How can I make the query such that I can choose both columns and relationships dynamically?

Comment: I think we need more info about the result of `parse_fields`.

Comment: Also is `relationships` the same as `requested_relationships`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry. I've revised it. I had to remove some stuff while sanitizing the code. Like mentioned in the revision, `parse_fields` returns the columns and relationships dynamically in the same format as if you called `ModelA.id` or `ModelA.my_relationship`.